# Hide scrollbars, if not necessary - Ace editor

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I've been experimenting with [Ace Editor](http://ace.c9.io/) and I've been trying to automatically "hide" (= not use the system defaults) the vertical/horizontal scrollbars, when not in use.

Is there a way? Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add `overflow:auto` css to the right element. I think that could be `.ace_scroller`. Give me example with scrollers or find by yourself using Object Inspector (Ctrl + Shift + I ; Chrome, FF, Opera).

## Edit:

There is your code:

```
body .ace_scrollbar-v {
    overflow-y: auto;
}

body .ace_scrollbar-h {
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

## Edit2:

Hide scrollbar If editor isn't hovered:

```
body .ace_scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
body .ace_editor:hover .ace_scrollbar {
    display: block;
}
```

Or with animation:

```
body .ace_scrollbar {
    -webkit-transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
       -moz-transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
         -o-transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
            transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0;
}
body .ace_editor:hover .ace_scrollbar {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Well, I've tried that (specifically on `.ace_scroller` you suggested) and the thing is it... adds another pair of scrollbars next to the one I was trying to "hide".

Comment: Find right element or provide example with scrollbars... I'm not a magician ;)

Comment: I just realized how it's work. Look again at the answer.

Comment: Hmm... Still nothing. The scrollbars are still there. (FYI, The testing is done on Safari only. And I'm not interested in *any* other browser)

Comment: This answer sets scrollbars to hide if text is short, but that's default behavior in ace and can be activated with `ace.setOptions({hScrollBarAlwaysVisible: false, vScrollBarAlwaysVisible: false})`, the question seems to be about hiding scrollbar when not hovered like on mac os.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to set the word wrap too.

editor.getSession().setUseWrapMode(true)